# PyPi package submission doesn't work but returns 200 response

Tags: python, pypi

I'm having trouble updating my PyPi packages. This issue occurs on both packages I maintain. It used to work now it doesn't.

Here's what I do:

`python setup.py sdist bdist_wininst upload -r pypi`

and here's what I get:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing django_stdimage.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to django_stdimage.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to django_stdimage.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'django_stdimage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'django_stdimage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating django-stdimage-0.4.0
creating django-stdimage-0.4.0/django_stdimage.egg-info
creating django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage
creating django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage/templates
creating django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage/templates/stdimage
making hard links in django-stdimage-0.4.0...
hard linking MANIFEST.in -> django-stdimage-0.4.0
hard linking README.rst -> django-stdimage-0.4.0
hard linking setup.py -> django-stdimage-0.4.0
hard linking django_stdimage.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/django_stdimage.egg-info
hard linking django_stdimage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/django_stdimage.egg-info
hard linking django_stdimage.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/django_stdimage.egg-info
hard linking django_stdimage.egg-info/top_level.txt -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/django_stdimage.egg-info
hard linking stdimage/__init__.py -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage
hard linking stdimage/fields.py -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage
hard linking stdimage/forms.py -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage
hard linking stdimage/utils.py -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage
hard linking stdimage/widgets.py -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage
hard linking stdimage/templates/stdimage/admin_widget.html -> django-stdimage-0.4.0/stdimage/templates/stdimage
Writing django-stdimage-0.4.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'django-stdimage-0.4.0' (and everything under it)
running bdist_wininst
running build
running build_py
installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage
copying build/lib/stdimage/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage
copying build/lib/stdimage/fields.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage
copying build/lib/stdimage/forms.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage/templates
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage/templates/stdimage
copying build/lib/stdimage/templates/stdimage/admin_widget.html -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage/templates/stdimage
copying build/lib/stdimage/utils.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage
copying build/lib/stdimage/widgets.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/stdimage
running install_egg_info
Copying django_stdimage.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst/PURELIB/django_stdimage-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating '/var/folders/rf/s7xtc35118d3kc3vhtmjcqcc0000gn/T/tmpZL46MD.zip' and adding '.' to it
adding 'PURELIB/django_stdimage-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'
adding 'PURELIB/django_stdimage-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO'
adding 'PURELIB/django_stdimage-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
adding 'PURELIB/django_stdimage-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'PURELIB/stdimage/__init__.py'
adding 'PURELIB/stdimage/fields.py'
adding 'PURELIB/stdimage/forms.py'
adding 'PURELIB/stdimage/utils.py'
adding 'PURELIB/stdimage/widgets.py'
adding 'PURELIB/stdimage/templates/stdimage/admin_widget.html'
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
Make sure that Python modules _winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/wininst' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting dist/django-stdimage-0.4.0.tar.gz to http://www.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
Submitting dist/django-stdimage-0.4.0.macosx-10.9-intel.exe to http://www.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

My `~/.pypirc` is as followed:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
repository: http://www.python.org/pypi
username: *********
password: *********
```

A look on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-stdimage) shows you that I wasn't able to update to v0.4.0 so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to `register` you package version as well:

```
python setup.py register sdist bdist_wininst upload -r pypi
```

Comment: That was new to me, but it worked tho I was asked to actually register, putting in my old credential worked.

Comment: The `register` command actually refers to the release, so you are going to need it any time you want to publish a new release.